# image field contains null values ,even after the payload is showing image data as well as other field data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, nestjs

**Registration form**
`

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import custom_axios from '../axios/AxiosSetup';
import { getLoginInfo } from '../utils/LoginInfo';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ApiConstants } from '../api/ApiConstants';
import ImageCapture from "../components/ImageCapture";


const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    vFirstName: Yup.string().required('First Name is required'),
    vLastName: Yup.string().required('Last Name is required'),
    vDateOfBirth: Yup.date()
    .required('Date of Birth is required')
    .max(new Date(), 'Date of Birth cannot be in the future')
    .test('valid-date', 'Invalid Date of Birth', (value) => {
      const dob = new Date(value);
      const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
      return dob.getFullYear() >= 1900 && dob.getFullYear() <= currentYear;
    }),
    vehicleNo: Yup.string().required('vehicle number is required'),
    vMobileNo: Yup.string().required('Contact Number is required').matches(/^\d{10}$/, 'Contact number must be a 10-digit number'),
    vAddress: Yup.string().required('Address is required'),
    visitorType: Yup.string().required('Visitor Type is required').oneOf(['Admin', 'Normal_user'], 'Invalid visitor Type Type'),
    
   
  });
const NewVisitor=()=>{

    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const[vPhoto,setVphoto]=useState('');
    const[vSignature,setVsignature]=useState('');


   const handleCapture=(imageSrc,fieldId)=>{
    
    if(fieldId=='vPhoto'){
      setVphoto(imageSrc);
    }
    else if(fieldId ==='vSignature'){
      setVsignature(imageSrc)
    }
   };
  
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      vFirstName: '',
      vLastName: '',
      vDateOfBirth: '',
      vehicleNo: '',
      vMobileNo: '',
      vAddress: '',
      visitorType: '',
      vPhoto: '',
      vSignature:'',
    },
    validationSchema,
    
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      const role = getLoginInfo()?.userType;
      if (role === 'Admin') {
        try {
            const formData =new FormData();
            formData.append('vFirstName', values.vFirstName);
            formData.append('vLastName', values.vLastName);
            formData.append('vDateOfBirth', values.vDateOfBirth);
            formData.append('vAddress', values.vAddress);
            formData.append('vMobileNo', values.vMobileNo);
            formData.append('vehicleNo', values.vehicleNo);
            formData.append('visitorType', values.visitorType);
            formData.append('vPhoto', vPhoto);
            formData.append('vSignature', vSignature);
         
           formData.forEach(function(value, key){
           console.log(key, value);
           });

           if (formData.has('vPhoto')) {
            // Submit the form data
          } else {
            console.error('vPhoto field is missing');
          }


          const response = await custom_axios.post(ApiConstants.VISITORS.ADD, formData,{
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
            
          });
          
          toast.success('User added successfully!!!');
          navigate('/usersPage');
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          toast.error('Error adding user. Please try again.');
        }
      } else {
        toast.info('Forbidden Resource');
      }
    },
  });

    return(
        <div>
          
        <Navbar />
        <h1 className="text-2xl text-black mr-4 rounded-lg text-center p-4 mb-2 mt-2 font-bold bg-blue-300">REGISTER NEW VISITOR HERE!</h1>
        <div className="container mx-auto">
          
          <div className="flex justify-center px-4 mt-1 my-12">
            <div className=" bg-blue-300 shadow-2xl mx-auto justify-center p-5 rounded-lg">
            {/* <h1 className="text-center font-bold text-xl">Enter Visitor Information Here!</h1>
              <h3 className="pt-4 text-2xl text-center"></h3> */}
              <form className="px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 bg-blue-300 rounded" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                {/* Username and Password */}
                <div className="mb-4 md:flex md:justify-between">
                  <div className="mb-4 md:mr-2 md:mb-0">
                    <label className="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-700" htmlFor="userName">
                      First Name
                    </label>
                    <input
                      {...formik.getFieldProps('vFirstName')}
                      className="w-full px-3 py-2 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded shadow appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                      id="vFirstName"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="First Name"
                    />
                    {formik.touched.vFirstName && formik.errors.vFirstName && (
                      <p className="text-red-500">{formik.errors.vFirstName}</p>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <div className="md:ml-2">
                    <label className="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-700" htmlFor="password">
                     Last Name
                    </label>
                    <input
                      {...formik.getFieldProps('vLastName')}
                      className="w-full px-3 py-2 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded shadow appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                      id="vLastName"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Last Name"
                    />
                    {formik.touched.vLastName && formik.errors.vLastName && (
                      <p className="text-red-500">{formik.errors.vLastName}</p>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-4">
                            <label
                              className="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-700"
                              htmlFor="shiftTime"
                            >
                              Date of Birth
                            </label>
                            <input
                              {...formik.getFieldProps('vDateOfBirth')}
                              className="w-full px-3 py-2 mb-3 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded shadow appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                              id="DateOfBirth"
                              type="Date"
                              placeholder="Date of birth here!"
                            />
                            {formik.touched.vDateOfBirth && formik.errors.vDateOfBirth && (
                      <p className="text-red-500">{formik.errors.vDateOfBirth}</p>
                    )}
                          </div>
                          <div className="mb-4 md:flex md:justify-between">
                            <div className="mb-4 md:mr-2 md:mb-0">
                              <label
                                className="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-700"
                                htmlFor="vehicleNo"
                              >
                                Vehicle Number
                              </label>
                              <input
                                {...formik.getFieldProps('vehicleNo')}
                                className="w-full px-3 py-2 mb-3 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded shadow appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                id="VehicleNo"
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Vehicle Number"
                              />
                              {formik.touched.vehicleNo && formik.errors.vehicleNo && (
                      <p className="text-red-500">{formik.errors.vehicleNo}</p>
                    )}
                              
                            </div>
                            <div className="md:ml-2">
                              <label
                                className="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-700"
                                htmlFor="contactNumberL"
                              >
                                Mobile Number
                              </label>
                              <input
                                {...formik.getFieldProps('vMobileNo')}
                                className="w-full px-3 py-2 mb-3 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded shadow appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                id="vMobileNo"
                                type="number"
                                placeholder="Contact Number"
                              />
                                {formik.touched.vMobileNo && formik.errors.vMobileNo && (
                      <p className="text-red-500">{formik.errors.vMobileNo}</p>
                    )}
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="mb-4">
                            <label
                              className="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-700"
                              htmlFor="contactNumberM"
                            >
                              Visitor Type
                            </label>
                            <select
                                {...formik.getFieldProps('visitorType')}
                                className="w-full px-3 py-2 mb-3 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded shadow appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                id="VisitorType"
                                defaultValue=""
                              >
                                <option value="" >
                                  Select Visitor Type
                                </option>
                                <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                                <option value="Normal_user">Normal_user</option>
                              </select>
                              {formik.touched.visitorType && formik.errors.visitorType && (
                      <p className="text-red-500">{formik.errors.visitorType}</p>
                    )}
                          </div>
  
                          <div className="mb-4 md:flex md:justify-between">
                  <div className="mb-4 md:mr-2 md:mb-0">
                    <label className="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-700" htmlFor="userName">
                      Address
                    </label>
                    <input
                      {...formik.getFieldProps('vAddress')}
                      className="w-full px-3 py-2 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded shadow appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                      id="vAddress"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="First Name"
                    />
                    {formik.touched.vAddress && formik.errors.vAddress && (
                      <p className="text-red-500">{formik.errors.vAddress}</p>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
                    <div className="mb-4">
                        <label className="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-700" htmlFor="PhotoImage">
                            Photo Image
                        </label>
                       <div 
                       id="vPhoto"
                       {...formik.getFieldProps('vPhoto')}
                       >
                       <ImageCapture
                       

                        onCapture={handleCapture}
                       fieldId='vPhoto'
                       />
                        {formik.touched.vPhoto && formik.errors.vPhoto && (
                            <p className="text-red-500">{formik.errors.vPhoto}</p>
                        )}
                       </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-4">
                        <label className="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-700" htmlFor="vSignature">
                            Signature
                        </label>
                       <div
                       id="vSignature"
                       {...formik.getFieldProps('vSignature')}
                       >
                       <ImageCapture 
                        onCapture={handleCapture} 
                        fieldId='vSignature'
                       />
                        {formik.touched.vSignature && formik.errors.vSignature && (
                            <p className="text-red-500">{formik.errors.vSignature}</p>
                        )}
                       </div>
                        
                    </div>

                        <div className="mb-8 text-center">
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="w-full px-4 py-2 font-bold text-white bg-gray-600 rounded-full hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                        >
                            Register
                        </button>
                        </div>
                <hr className="mb-4 border-t" />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
export default NewVisitor;
```

`

**Image Capture component

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import Webcam from 'react-webcam';

const ImageCapture = ({ onCapture, fieldId }) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');
  const webcamRef = useRef(null);
  const [cameraDevices, setCameraDevices] = useState([]);
  const [selectedDeviceId, setSelectedDeviceId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Enumerate available media devices (cameras)
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
      const cameraDevices = devices.filter((device) => device.kind === 'videoinput');
      setCameraDevices(cameraDevices);

      // Select the first camera as the default option (you can change this logic)
      if (cameraDevices.length > 0) {
        setSelectedDeviceId(cameraDevices[0].deviceId);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const capture = useCallback(() => {
    const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
    setImage(imageSrc);
    
    onCapture(imageSrc, fieldId);
  }, [onCapture, fieldId]);

  const handleDeviceChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedDeviceId(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="webcam-container">
      <div className="webcam-img">
        {image === '' ? (
          <>
            <Webcam
              audio={false}
              height={200}
              ref={webcamRef}
              screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
              width={220}
              videoConstraints={{
                width: 220,
                height: 200,
                facingMode: 'user',
                deviceId: selectedDeviceId, // Specify the selected camera device
              }}
            />
            <select onChange={handleDeviceChange} value={selectedDeviceId}>
              {cameraDevices.map((device) => (
                <option key={device.deviceId} value={device.deviceId}>
                  {device.label}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </>
        ) : (
          <img src={image} alt="Captured" />
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        {image !== '' ? (
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setImage('');
            }}
            className="webcam-btn w-md px-4 py-2 font-bold text-white bg-gray-600 rounded-full hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          >
            Retake Image
          </button>
        ) : (
          <button
            className="webcam-btn w-md px-4 py-2 font-bold text-white bg-gray-600 rounded-full hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            onClick={capture}
          >
            Capture photo
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageCapture;
```

**whenever i fill the form in the frontend , fill the text fields and capture the images using react-webcam . what is happening is data is stored properly in the fields when i console log the formdata which consists of all the data , that formdata shows all the data , what happens after that when i try to submit this data backend shows error Vphoto field is empty  , i checked  the payload as well the payload shows the whole data accurately. i am not able to figure out where i am doing wrong . my backend is in nestjs when i try to enter the same fields through postman , the data is entered in the database accurately when i try to do the same from the frontend its showing error. Backend is working properly when i try to enter data using POSTMAN, but it shows errors when i try to enter data through frontend ,**
**

Comment: Does the backend give you logs of what request was received? Can you examine the network tab to see if the data being submitted has the correct headers, payload, MIME type, etc?

Comment: I would recommend that you build a sample app that contains only a prototype of the specific function you are having problems with. it is better to post on stack overflow with the _smallest_ reproduction app possible (the fewest lines of code needed to reproduce the problem)-- your code samples are very long and probably contain a lot of stuff unrelated to the specific question.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i have done the backend part in nestjs , when i try add data using postman , in the form of multipart/formdata , data is entered into the the database wihout any errors , including image files . after that i made a frontend and in the frontend when i tried to enter images through uploading from pc , that also worked properly , now the actual problem was to capture the images through webcam and enter that to the database , now i am facing issues , i am unable to figure out whether there is some issue with the type of image data that i am trying to upload .

Comment: the backend logic is for accepting files , but when we capture image through webcam its in base64 format which is a long string of text, can anybody help me with that , is this a format issue